# Open-source alternatives to UPX for compressing executable files

Tags: open-source, file-compression

I'm looking for open-source alternatives to `UPX` (`Ultimate Packer for eXecutables`).

Reasons:

1. Part of the UPX code is protected by copyright.
2. UPX embeds information about the creators' copyrights into compressed executable files and prohibits its removal.

Are there any open-source alternatives similar to UPX that allow running the compressed executable file without unpacking it?

Perhaps there is a way to pack a compressed file from another program into a new executable?